# How do I create a custom User Control in ASP.net that updates itself asynchronously?

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, asp.net-4.0

I wish to create a reusable Drop-down user control that retrieves data from the server to populate itself.

The server is also making an asynchronous call to an api endpoint to retrieve the data that will be used in the dropdown as follows:

```
private void downloadDropdownData(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var client = new WebClient();
    client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(OnFinished);
    client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://docform-nodeapi.herokuapp.com/letterinfo"));
}
```

My problem is that if another control does a partial post back before the download is completed, the previous request to populate the dropdown gets canceled. How do you run multiple async post backs simultaneously in ASP.net?

Comment: Couldn't you make that request from within the web-browser using `XMLHttpRequest`?

Comment: @Dai For this example I could do it from the browser but I wish to learn how to do it the way I described for future implementations